# How to integrate Php array to Javascript Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am working on ajax and php,I want to use Php array in javascript,But right not unable to integrate Php array to javascript,
Here is my Controller code where i am getting Php array as json(Using Json encode)

```
function GetFollowingCoinUsers()
        {
            $CoinId=$_POST['coin_id'];
            $result = $this->M_main->GetAllCoinFollower($CoinId);
            $UserId=array();
            foreach($result as $res)
            {
                $UserId[]=$res['UserId'];
            }
            echo json_encode($UserId);
        }
```

Above code give me result in following way

```
["463","500","505"]
```

And i am trying to use this array in Javascript/Ajax Response

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Main/GetFollowingCoinUsers',
            data: {coin_id:coin_id},
            success: function (datan) {
                    var cars = datan;
                    let text = "";
                    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                      text += cars[i] + "<br>";
                    }
                    alert(text);
                    
            }
        });
```

Comment: var cars = JSON.parse(datan);

Comment: The above is correct, but next time, it makes the question a lot clearer if you mention what error you're getting when you try to run the code...

Comment: @Adyson: you can see what i tried

Comment: Yes I can. But like I said, it would be a lot clearer for people if you **also** show the error message you got when you ran the code. Not all problems are as trivial to spot as this one. This code ought to produce either an error or at least unexpected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
yourArray = [];

JSON.parse(yourArray.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
```